# Django second to last iteration of for loop

Tags: python, django

tabbed_fieldset.html states:

```
    if forloop.counter0 > 0 and forloop.last
           #do stuff`
```

I just wrote in a separate file:

```
for fieldset in adminform
    if not forloop.last
        include "admin/includes/tabbed_fieldset.html"
    else
         include "admin/includes/geo_fieldset.html"
     endif 
 endfor
```

So now `tabbed_fieldset.html`'s code won't work anymore because if it is `forloop.last`, it wouldn't even be in `tabbed_fieldset.html`, it would be in `geo_fieldset.html`.

Is there a simple way to change `forloop.last` into `forloop second to last`?

Comment: Could you provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: That really doesn't look like Python to me.

Comment: I see now; there's a [Django Template Language](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/language/).

Comment: You're right. I'm so noob I can't tell the dif between Python and Django. derp! Thanks. I'll fix that.

Comment: can't you "tag" your fieldset with a value and check on it in your template ?

Comment: I don't think it looks like Django template language too as special keywords like `if` and `else` are generally wrapped with `{% %}`.

Comment: They are wrapped with those. I took them out for easier reading. Sorry!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks for the code! Check out this website: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/

> **The for loop sets a number of variables available within the loop:**
>
> forloop.counter - The current iteration of the loop (1-indexed)
>
> forloop.counter0 -    The current iteration of the loop (0-indexed)
>
> forloop.revcounter -  The number of iterations from the end of the loop (1-indexed)
>
> forloop.revcounter0 - The number of iterations from the end of the loop 
>   (0-indexed)
>
> forloop.first -   True if this is the first time through the loop
>
> forloop.last -    True if this is the last time through the loop
>
> forloop.parentloop -  For nested loops, this is the loop surrounding the current one

Basically, you would use `forloop.revcounter` or `forloop.revcounter0`

```
for fieldset in adminform
    if forloop.revcounter0 > 1
        include "admin/includes/tabbed_fieldset.html"
    else
        include "admin/includes/geo_fieldset.html"
    endif
endfor
```